# undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Anyone know how I can fix this error? Here's more information -

error message:

```
NoMethodError in PostsController#create
undefined method `update' for nil:NilClass
```

The PostsController create:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @twitter_user.update(@post.content)
  end
```

Here's how @twitter_user is defined in my user.rb model

```
  def twitter
    unless @twitter_user
      provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
      @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:token => provider.token, :secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
    end
    @twitter_user
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: In your PostsController's `create` method, just how does that `@twitter_user` variable get its value assigned?

Comment: -> You have to create a new instance of @twitter_user first. Or you want something like User.twitter.update ... please give more informations ;)

Comment: Maybe you ment `current_user.twitter` instead of `@twitter_user` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model and the controller don't share instance variables, so `@twitter_user` inside `PostsController` is not the same as the one inside the `User`  class (which I suppose derives from `ActiveRecord::Base`). You have to initialize `@twitter_user` inside the controller.

You can refactor your code like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def twitter_user
    provider = self.authentications.find_by_provider('twitter')
    Twitter::Client.new(:token => provider.token, 
                        :secret => provider.secret)
  rescue
    return nil
  end
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # I suppose your User instance is accessible 
    # through the method current_user
    @twitter_user = current_user.twitter_user
    @twitter_user.update(@post.content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If `@twitter_user` is defined in your User model you can't access it in the controller. A variable in a method with an `@` prefix belongs to an instance of that class.

If you want to access `@twitter_user` in the controller, perhaps move that twitter method to the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController
  def twitter
    unless @twitter_user
      provider = User.find_by_provider('twitter')
      @twitter_user = Twitter::Client.new(:token => provider.token, :secret => provider.secret) rescue nil
    end
    @twitter_user
  end
end
```

Then you can access it in any controller method with `twitter`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    twitter.update(@post.content)   
  end
```